# Reading and writing file properly (handling errors, etc.) using QFile?

Tags: c++, file, qt, error-handling, qt5

Is there a good tutorial or could someone guide me through the process of handling files with `QFile`?
I need to handle them *properly*, raise proper errors and make sure that I check the errors at least.

So far I've been using this code:

```
QFile f("/home/skamah/documents/myfile.txt");
if (!f.exists())
    QMessageBox("File error", "File doesn't exist.").show();
QTextStream in(&file);
QString content = in.readAll();
```

However, I feel like this is pretty premitive way of reading files; from qt doc, I've found out that there's a method called `error()` which returns an int value, depending on which error it gives.
Should I use that?
And is there a convention on what kind of errors to raise?

Answer (score 1):

Qt documentation is the best guide. If you have read it, you'd know that `error()` method returns `QFile::FileError` value, not int.

For each method (`open`, `read` etc) there is a way to determine if it succeded or not. It's described in the method's documentation. The basic rule: if you want to ensure that everything goes well, you need to check it after each method call. After you determined that something is wrong, it's your choice how to notify the calling code or the user about it, and what additional information to provide. You can use exceptions, for example.

However, QFile lacks ability to determine the real cause of error. For example, it can't determine if a file can't be written because no space is left on disk. And Qt doesn't use exceptions internally, so you need to check errors manually after each call.

Comment: Well isn't `QFile::FileError` just an enum with int values? That's what it says on the documentation. And I couldn't find anything too useful from the documentation, but I'll guess I'll read through it again... :P So I should just always implement my own checks if everything is good or not?

Comment: Yes, you should. There is no built-in ability to check everything at once.